# Selecting distinct columns with dynamic rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-automation

My data have 10+ columns and from that i want to select three columns and **further format those three columns**, but the no. of rows are not fixed so I'm unable to select all those three columns at once.
Here is what I'm trying to do

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G2:H" & lastrow, "J2:J" & lastrow).Select
```

But this is selecting I columns as well.
I tried this also

```
Range("G2:H & lastrow, J2:J" &lastrow).select
```

But this gave me error as expected.

Comment: what columns do you want to select?

Comment: Columns G,H and J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intersect(Range("G:H, J:J"), Rows("2:" & lastrow)).Select
```

Comment: @Digvijay, did you get through it?

Comment: Yes thanks it is selecting those columns, but there is some error with how further formatting happen using intersect to select.
I'm converting these selected columns to number format Using
`with selection
.numberformat = "0"`
`.value = .value`
when I'm selecting columns normally it's working fine, but using intersect creates `#NA` entries.

Comment: not contiguous cells must be handled differently than contiguous ones. but don't make your question a "chamaleon" one by changing it with _new_ issues as soon as _original_ ones get solved. Since I solved the _original_ selection issue you may want to mark answer as accepted. while for _new_ ones you should post a _new_ question. thank you

Comment: that was not my intention, I thought that this is what I should do i.e update the question here itself. I'll post a new question.